# Workaround ensure_loaded/1 GNU Prolog?

Tags: prolog, gnu-prolog

Is there a workaround to make ensure_loaded/1 work
in GNU Prolog as it works in many other Prolog systems?
The goal is to have a preamble so that the rest of
code can use ensure_loaded/1 independent of whether which
Prolog system I use.

I tried the following:

```
:- multifile(term_expansion/2).
term_expansion((:- ensure_loaded(X)),
     (:- atom_concat('<base>\\', X, Y),
     include(Y))).
```

But the following query doesn't work:

```
:- ensure_loaded('suite.p').
```

The path calculation itself is not the issue of the question, 
but the redefinition of a directive in GNU Prolog. There is
another directive that causes problems: meta_predicate/1. The
byte code crashes as follows:

[image: GNU Fatal]

Bye

Answer (score 2):

A *partial* solution is:

```
ensure_loaded(File) :-
    absolute_file_name(File, Path),
    (   predicate_property(_, prolog_file(Path)) ->
        true
    ;   consult(Path)
    ).
```

It assumes that the file defines at least one predicate but that's a sensible assumption. However, there's seems to be no way to override the native, non-functional, definition of the `ensure_loaded/1` directive. A workaround would be to wrap the `ensure_loaded/1` directive within an `initialization/1` directive. For example:

```
:- initialization(ensure_loaded('suite.pl')).
```

Hence this being a partial solution as we're really defining an `ensure_loaded/1` *predicate*, not a *directive*.

Comment: A **necessary** functionality to be able to define an `ensure_loaded/1` directive or predicate is to be able to query the system if a file is already loaded, which is accomplished in my reply by the call to `predicate_property/2`, which is not a straightforward solution. That's the main contribution in my post. The call to `absolute_file_name/2` is necessary as the `prolog_file/1` property uses absolute file paths. The `include/1` directive does nothing in helping finding if a file is already loaded.

Answer (score 0):

My current speculation is, that it is impossible with
the standard distribution of GNU Prolog 1.4.4. The
docu says:

> The GNU Prolog compiler (section 4.4) automatically calls
>   expand_term/2 on each Term1 read in. However, in the current release,
>   only DCG transformation are done by the compiler (i.e.
>   term_expansion/2 cannot be used). To use term_expansion/2, it is
>   necessary to call expand_term/2 explicitly.

I also tried to inject some Prolog code for term_expansion/2
via the command line, but to no awail. Although the tool chain
has options such as -O, -L, -A that pass options to other tools.
There is not really an option that passes a Prolog text to the
pl2wam, in course of the execution of a consult/1 issued inside
the top-level.

At least this are my results so far.

Bye